# Socket.io client does not emit based on available memory/cpu in tab?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, phaser-framework

I've discovered an odd quirk using socket.io. I have a simple setup: two clients on separate computers and a node.js server on one of the clients. The tick rate (time between each message) is 100ms (i.e. something perfectly reasonable). Both clients communicate to the server with socket.emit and the server sends the message back to both clients. Works great. Well, here's what's odd ...

This is for a webgl web game, mind you, so there is a lot of stuff happening in the tab. When things really start to cook up in the game and the tab thread starts to use more system resources, the socket ceases to emit to the server. The game is running fine, perhaps a drop in FPS but no serious crash or anything like that. In addition, I can tell the socket.emit code is being executed (or at least called) every 100ms just like normal (by executing a console.log directly before it). But despite that, the server doesn't get the message, sent from the client with socket.emit. I know this because I am console.logging every communication that makes it to the server...

I can literally increase the size of the window (which sucks up more resources, because the webgl renderer has to do more work) and the messages will cease to be received on the server when the window gets too big. Bizarre! Why would sucking up more system resources cause socket.emit messages to not reach the server? And if it did function like that, why wouldn't I receive a message/error/warning on the client or the server? I have difficulty believing socket.emit just **decides** to not work based on how much system resources there are.

On the clients I'm using the latest chrome, Phaser.IO (pixi.js for the renderer) and mac osx. What the hell is going on??? Many thanks.

Comment: Is your client allowing the message queue to flow so incoming TCP messages can get processed or is it possible the game engine is sucking up all possible CPU and not letting other events get processed?

Comment: I find it unlikely the client is sucking up all possible CPU as the game is running mostly smoothly when this happens and all other processes are running fine. that's what's bizarre.

Comment: If you insert this `setInterval(function() {console.log("tick")}, 1000);` into your client code, do you see those console messages in the debug console every second?

Comment: yeah, like i said "I can tell the socket.emit code is being executed (or at least called) every 100ms just like normal (by executing a console.log directly before it)"

Comment: That isn't the same as what I asked.  You're just verifying that `.emit()` is getting called.  I want to know if event queue messages are getting processed and `setTimeout()` is a test of that.

Comment: Just tested. You must be on to something there. The setInterval doesn't fire every second when the problem happens ... it slows down a lot and fires more like every year! I know phaser uses RAF (request animation frame) so perhaps that is why the game engine is unaffected. still, my networking code should be entirely dependent on RAF and not setInterval - so I'm curious as to why socket.emit is not working. Is it likely socket.io is reliant upon setInterval/Timout?

Comment: This probably means something is hogging the single JS thread and not letting the event queue get serviced.  It's not surprising that networking calls don't work in that circumstance.  There is probably a way to tell your gaming engine to allow some cycles for the event queue.

Comment: that makes sense. is it possible to run socket.io in a separate thread using a web worker? sending the message to the worker which emits to the server (instead of directly to the server)? Would that likely solve my problem?

Comment: I don't personally know if socket.io is webWorker safe, but it should be theoretically possible.  But, you will need a working event queue if you're going to be able to communicate with the webWorker via messaging.

Comment: Was thinking i could communicate with the webWorker via RAF (like the game framework does)

Comment: You can try.  JS apps that don't service their event queue are very likely to have issues.

Comment: I agree. Opening an issue on git hub with Phaser.